# Django Rest Framework ViewSet doesn't filter by field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a `ModelViewSet` with `SearchFilter` and `OrderingFilter`. Everything works fine, but when I try to filter by one specific field (like `localhost:8000:/es/countries/?code=MX`), it returns all records even when only one matches the criteria. When I use a generic search, like `localhost:8000:/es/countries/?search=MX`, it works fine.

This is my `ViewSet`:

```
class CountryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = models.Country.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CountrySerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter, OrderingFilter,)
    search_fields = ('name', 'code', 'calling_code')
    filter_fields = ('name', 'code', 'calling_code')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [DjangoFilterBakend](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend).

In your code you are using search_fields, it only works with search param. (as it is for searching and for filtering!!)

You need to add DjangoFilterBackend same as you have added SearchFilter and OrderingFilter in filter_backends field.
And then mention the filter that you want in filter_fields field.

For eg:

```
class CountryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
   queryset = models.Country.objects.all()
   serializer_class = serializers.CountrySerializer
   filter_backends = (SearchFilter, OrderingFilter, DjangoFilterBackend)
   search_fields = ('name', 'code', 'calling_code')
   filter_fields = ('name', 'code', 'calling_code')
```

You will also have to install django-filter.

```
pip install django-filter
```

Finally add `django_filter` to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ....
    'django_filters',
]
```

Comment: I followed your suggestion, but I got this error: `django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: django_filters/rest_framework/form.html`. Thanks for your help

Comment: Add django_filters as INSTALLED_APPS for template rendering